# PHP echo if result

Tags: php, if-statement, input, call, echo

I want to echo

```
<input type="button" name="answer" value="loopedSlider" onclick="showDiv()">
```

on the

```
if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "youtube", true));
```

how can I do that?  real example

```
if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "youtube", true)); 
echo  <input type="button" name="answer" value="loopedSlider">
```

something like this, can you help me ?

Comment: What technology are you using? wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "youtube", true)){ 
    echo  '<input type="button" name="answer" value="loopedSlider" onclick="showDiv()">';
}else{
    // something else
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) it worked, i have another question, how can i echo inside wordpress text editor ?

Comment: I wouldn't know, never used WordPress. Try on your own first and if you have problems post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want show that input base on condition, I think this should be ok

```
   if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "youtube", true)):
      echo  '<input type="button" name="answer" value="loopedSlider"  onclick="showDiv()">';
  endif;
```

Comment: Thank you :) it worked, i have another question, how can i echo inside wordpress text editor ?

Comment: I don't use wordpress sorry.But I think you can just write  <?php code here ?> and execute it. I really don't use it .  But check this post, it might help . http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/execute-php-in-wordpress-post-page-and-widget-sidebar/